# API to set and query Email Routing

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is there anyway to set and query an individual account's Email Routing setting via the Directory API?  I don't see any reference to this in the docs. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is available in Directory API but, you might want to check the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings) since the Email Setting API is deprecated and moved to Gmail API. [Managing auto-forwarding settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_auto-forwarding_settings) - To manage auto-forwarding in the Gmail API, use the [Settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings) resource. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is a part of the Google Workspace Admin SDK:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings#managing_email_gateway_and_routing